# Optimisation of random seating

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory, optimization, maxima-minima

I have 41 delegates and 6 tables.

Each delegate must attend each table once.

I would like to minimize the number of times delegates sit together and maximize the distance between each delegate.

How do I write this down mathematically and what is the best approach to solve this?

So far I have used the numbers 0 to 41 to represent the seats at each table and assumed 7 seats at each table with 0 being the empty seat rotated through the tables at each round. This ensures 1 empty seat in each round at different tables.

After the initial start positions, there are 5 moves in total.

Using the numbers 0 to 41 allows me to create 6 table arrays with a sum of 861 and 6 Move position arrays each having sum of 861.

Comment: Here is an example of a similar problem [(link)](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/10/scheduling-business-dinners.html)